# Irreducible algebraic group is a product of its two open subsets

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be an algebraic group, and let $G$ be irreducible as an algebraic variety. Let $U, V$ be two open subsets of $G$.

> Prove that any element $g \in G$ can be represented as $uv$ where $u \in U$ and $v \in V$.

I tried to suppose that it's not true, and then if $s$  can not be represented as a product, then there will be $sU \neq U$ and $sV \neq V$ two open sets. (I assume that the multiplication of the group by an element of an algebraic group induces an open map however I can't justify that.)   If we had proved that $U*V$ is a group i.e. that any $v_1uv_2$ can be represented as $u' v'$ then it would mean that $sUV$ and $UV$ doesn't intersect

That's my idea but I can't think of making it work.

Comment: Hint: $s \in UV \Leftrightarrow Us \cap V \neq \emptyset$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The irreducibility is equal to the condition that every open set is dense. By density, for any $s$, $s \, (V)^{-1} \cap U$ is not empty, because this is an intersection of a dense and an open sets. then take $u$ inside the intersection and $s v^{-1} = u$.